# PFQueryTableViewController crashes when "Load More" is tapped (pagination)

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pagination, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

I've looked at similar questions and tried different solutions to no avail. I've implemented PFQueryTableViewController in my iOS app, and I've followed Parse iOS documents. Everything works well, except when I tap on "Load More" to get the next x number of Parse objects, the app crashes with the following message:

"*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]"

I know what the message means, but since I am using the PFQueryTableViewController instead of the usual UITableViewController, I am not sure how I can troubleshoot this range problem.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So for those of you who are interested, the reason why the pagination crashed is because I've implemented the following method, which the example on Parse document didn't.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

So in order for you to reload data without crashing, following code needs to be implemented:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row <= (self.objects!.count - 1) {

      //These are the cells populated by your PFQuery objects
      //Do whatever you want to do with the selected cell  

    } else {

        //This is if the "Load More" cell is selected

        self.loadNextPage()

    }
}
```